# Can't pass a variable from php to exec

Tags: php, bash, variables, unix, sed

I have some PHP code which gets the contents from `"php://input"`.

```
if (!isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Now, I'm trying to remove the `XML` tags from `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` using sed, like this:

```
exec("/usr/bin/sed -e 's/\<3\>//g' -e 's/\<\/3\>//g' $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA");
```

Then, I try echoing `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` like this:

```
echo("$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA");
```

But it still returns it with `<3>` and `</3>`. Seems like sed can't read the variable.

What can I do to fix this? I get no error messages.

Comment: The arguments to sed are filenames not raw data. sed then sends the modified output to standard output it doesn't modify (by default) the input file and *cannot* modify data read from standard input.

Comment: i didn't find any replacement part in the above sed command.

Comment: @EtanReisner So, what can i do?

Comment: Don't use sed for this - just use [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) or even better [`strip_tags`](http://www.php.net/strip_tags)? If you wish to parse the XML, use [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/SimpleXML).

Comment: Yeah, im very new, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use strip_tags() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php - does exactly what you want sed to do without the horrible security implications.